# why checking for undefined from a function call causes SSR error, but not directly using `typeof` in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, server-side-rendering

Can anyone please help explain this unexpected behavior?

I have a working `useSessionStorage` hook from https://typeofnan.dev/using-session-storage-in-react-with-hooks/ that looks like the following:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function getSessionStorageOrDefault(key, defaultValue) {
  if (typeof sessionStorage === 'undefined') {
    return defaultValue;
  }
  const stored = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
  if (!stored) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
  return JSON.parse(stored);
}

function useSessionStorage(key, defaultValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(
    getSessionStorageOrDefault(key, defaultValue)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
}

export default useSessionStorage;
```

Notice how I check to make sure `sessionStorage` is defined in order to make sure it works in SSR:

```js
  if (typeof sessionStorage === 'undefined') {
    return defaultValue;
  }
```

Now when I try to replace `typeof sessionStorage === 'undefined'` with a call to a utility method called `isUndefined`, I get SSR error that `sessionStorage is not defined`.

Here is the `isUndefined` utility method

```js
export function isUndefined(value) {
  return typeof value === 'undefined';
}
```

And here is the modified `useSessionStorage` hook that calls `isUndefined` and SSR no longer works:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { isUndefined } from 'utils/lang';

function getSessionStorageOrDefault(key, defaultValue) {
  if (isUndefined(sessionStorage)) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
  const stored = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
  if (!stored) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
  return JSON.parse(stored);
}

function useSessionStorage(key, defaultValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(
    getSessionStorageOrDefault(key, defaultValue)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
}

export default useSessionStorage;
```

Why does `typeof sessionStorage === 'undefined'` work, but replacing it with `isUndefined(sessionStorage)` causes it to no longer work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to just a basic fact of javascript and all programming languages that I can think of off the top of my head. When you call `isUndefined(sessionStorage)`, you are attempting to pass the the memory location identified by an identifier called `sessionStorage` [by value](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/) to the function `isUndefined`. In order to do that, the `sessionStorage` identifier needs to be looked up and its value read, which is of course impossible since it hasn't yet been [declared](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp), hence the error.

On the other hand, [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an *operator*. You aren't passing the value of `sessionStorage` to it, but rather asking it to look up that identifier's type. It just so happens that `typeof`'s behavior when it is passed an undeclared identifier is to return `'undefined'` instead of throwing an error.

Finally, it's worth noting that a *declared* but as yet *undefined* variable in javascript has a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/undefined) of `undefined`, so you *can* pass it to a function.

Hopefully the following is clear:

```js
function isUndefined(identifier) {
  return typeof identifier === "undefined"
}

let x = true
let y

isUndefined(x) // false
isUndefined(y) // true
isUndefined(z) // Uncaught ReferenceError: z is not defined
```

It might be clearer if the message was "z has not been declared," but hopefully you now understand what it's really telling you.